# IN Statement in VBScript

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio, vbscript

Is there an equivalent of the `IN` Statement for VBScript?

I am looking to create an `If` statement for column visibility which checks if a particular value was selected in a parameter. This value is multi-valued so I need to test if it's present in a list of values.

I have a lookup table which assigns a value to 4 different call types:

```sql
SELECT 1 as CALL_ORDER,'Welcome Call' AS [TEXT], '1' AS [VALUE]
UNION
SELECT 2 as CALL_ORDER,'Month One Call' AS [TEXT], '2' AS [VALUE]
UNION
SELECT 3 as CALL_ORDER,'Month Two Call' AS [TEXT], '3' AS [VALUE]
UNION
SELECT 4 as CALL_ORDER,'Month Six Call' AS [TEXT], '4' AS [VALUE]
```

visual studio :

[image]

The user has an option to select a multiple number of these options and I need to test if, when run, a specific value is present in the list.

**For example:**

```vb
If 1 IN(PARAMETERS!CALL_TYPE.VALUE) Then ...
```

Not sure how you would do this in VBScript.

Comment: This isn't VBScript. Guessing from the screenshot, it's likely VB.NET.

Answer (score 1):

VBScript doesn't have an `In` or `Contains` statement/operator.

I think the most common way to do `In` or `Contains` checks in VBScript is to build a [dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x4k5wbx4.aspx) with the possible values and check the actual value against that dictionary:

```vb
Set ref = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
ref.Add "foo", True
ref.Add "bar", True

var = "foo"
If ref.Exists(var) Then    'value exists
    '...
End If

var = "baz"
If ref.Exists(var) Then    'value doesn't exist
    '...
Else
    '...
End If
```

Another common approach is to use multiples of 2 as flags in an integer value:

```vb
Const FOO = 1
Const BAR = 2
Const BAZ = 4

var = 5
If (var And FOO) = FOO Then    'value exists
    '...
End If

If (var And BAR) = BAR Then    'value doesn't exist
    '...
Else
    '...
End If
```

Depending on your actual requirements you may also be able to use a [`Select Case`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ef9w614.aspx) statement:

```vb
Select Case var
    Case "foo": 'do some
    Case "bar": 'do other
    Case Else:  'everything else
End Select
```

Comment: So each of those call options are a column. I need to allow the user to select which columns to show by using multi valued parameter. So I need to put an expression on the visibility section of the column to say if the column isn't chosen in the parameter then hide it

Comment: Do a check for each column and hide/display the column depending on the result?

Comment: Yeh so I have assigned each column a value in a lookup table above so need to check if it is selected in the parameter.

Comment: Sorry, but you're being too vague. You need to provide a lot more context to your SQL statement if you expect more than what is in my answer.

Comment: Ive included an image above of the parameter option. Each one of those options are an individual column in my report and have been assigned a value in the lookup table. I need to add an expression to each column which says if that column wasn't selected In the list above , then hide the column

Comment: That image doesn't explain anything at all.

Comment: Agreed, question is still a bit vague. We'd need to see more of your VBS program and how you're getting the call type selections to process.

Answer (score -1):

I would simply use the InStr function. E.g. I want to solve something like this:
a = 2
....Where a in (12,23,45)

Then I'd use
a = Cstr(2)
... if Instr("12,23,45",a)>0 then ...